# Add settings to driver in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I am trying to add some settings to my driver in selenium but can seem to make them work.

Im trying to add

```
{ 
 "DEVELOPER_MODE":false,
 "AUTOMATION_MODE":true,
 "AUTOMATION_LAUNCH_URL":"{whatever_url_you_want_to_test_with}"
}
```

to my driver file

```
     public static WebDriver startDriverTwo() {
        String projectLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", projectLocation + "/chromedriver.exe");
       

        ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
        opt.addArguments("start-maximized");
        opt.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        opt.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        opt.addArguments("--window-size=1920x1080");
        opt.addArguments("--disable-cache");
        //options.addArguments("--headless");
        opt.addArguments("--disable-application-cache");
        opt.addArguments("--disk-cache-size=0");
        opt.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
        opt.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
        opt.addArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable");
        opt.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        opt.addArguments("disable-infobars")

        //Enter the path of your Electron app
        opt.setBinary("pathtoelectronapp.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
        System.out.println("opening app");
        return driver;


    }
```

I have tried

```
setExperimentalOption()
setProperty()
```

But neither of these work? any idea how i can work these in?

Answer (score 1):

`DEVELOPER_MODE` - you got that right, it's `opt.addArguments("--disable-extensions");`

I'm little bit confused with these settings, since:

`AUTOMATION_MODE` - isn't this always true, when using Selenium?

`AUTOMATION_LAUNCH_URL` - you mean `driver.get(URL)` ?

Comment: Ah ok i see, basically im launching an electron app rather than chrome, and the url im using "launches" another window (which cant be interacted with) when i use driver.get(URL) so i need it to be "preloaded" already. On my local computer I have a json with these settings in the '%APPDATA% file and it works perfectly but when i launch form selenium these settings arent taken into consideration